# Controller in Appdelegate is never released

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, strong-typing

I have a strong reference in my AppDelegate and when I pop controller it isn't being released.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) MenuViewController        *menuViewController;
```

This controller is not being decollated at all because I nslog dealloc and it isn't appearing. Is there a way around this without putting this property somewhere else? I am assuming because Appdelegate is a singleton and all the properties stay alive throughout app life cycle.

Comment: Yeah, it's not going to be deallocated automatically, but you can manually set menuViewController to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're using this reference, but you can make it a `weak` pointer:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MenuViewController *menuViewController;
```

Set the pointer after you have initialized and presented the `menuViewController`.

If you have to initialize the `menuViewController` first and keep a reference for a later use, then you should set `self.menuViewController = nil` when you don't need it anymore.